# how to set Role by default in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net

I have two `Roles "Administrator" , " Basic USer"`. I want when somebody register by default he is in role "Basic User".
i trying to find in web administration tool but can't find it .

Comment: register as in u have a login page? elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Probably do that through code e.g. when the user is created, call `Roles.AddUserToRole("UserName", "Role");`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you may want to use AddUserToRole method of Roles API. Check out [this](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.in/2009/10/easy-default-roles-for-new-users-with.html) link that shows how to do it: